# Equivalence between Quantum Error Correcting codes and uniqueness of the $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

In quantum error correction, two stabilizer codes are considered to be equivalent if they differ by a local Clifford transformation or a qubit permutation. Represented as a tableau, these set of transformations establish an equivalence class between different tableaus that represent equivalent codes.

The literature suggests that, using this notion of code equivalence, there is a unique $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code with 4 cyclic stabilizer generators $g_1 = XZZX1,~g_2 = 1XZZX, \dots $ and logical basis $X_L = XXXXX$, $Z_L = ZZZZZ$. I have no problem in generating a tableau for such a representation of the code, and I can also verify that it is indeed a $d=3$ code by checking that the  (Knill-Laflamme) error-correcting conditions are satisfied for a standard symmetric depolarizing channel.

However, I have also been able to find a $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code (i.e. I can satisfy the same Knill-Laflamme equations as in the previous code) represented by a tableau in which both $X_L$ and $Z_L$ are weight 3 Pauli strings. To me it doesn't seem that such a code can be mapped to the standard $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code that I've described in the previous paragraph using only local Clifford transformations. The reason is that I don't see a way in which the weight of the logical operators can be changed using these transformations.

My question(s) are thus the following:

1. In which sense is the $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code unique?
2. Is it true that two different tableaus can only represent equivalent codes if all the weights of their Pauli strings are the same?

I'm aware of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283008/equivalent-quantum-codes but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It might help if you showed us your alternative code... (Also, remember that stabilizers and logical operators can be re-written as products of each other. So $X_L g_1$ is just as good a way of writing $X_L$ (and is a weight 3 Pauli string).)

Comment: Sure, but what is the circuit that maps the tableau with $X_L$ to a new tableau where the old $X_L$ gets replaced by $X_L g_1$ ? Understanding how it's done or whether it is even necessary to begin with might be the root of my confusion.

Comment: You don't need a circuit. It *is* the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** 1. The code is unique under the stated equivalence. 2. No.

### Weight of a logical operator is ill-defined

The crux of the issue is that the weight of a logical operator is ill-defined. Logical operator is not a single Pauli operator in the $n$-qubit Pauli group $\mathcal{P}_n$, but a *coset* $X_L\mathcal{S}$ of the stabilizer group $\mathcal{S}$ where $X_L$ is some *representative* of the logical operator.

For example, in the $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code folks typically choose $X_L=XXXXX$, but $g_1=XZZXI\in\mathcal{S}$, so $X_Lg_1\equiv IYYIX\in X_L\mathcal{S}$ is another valid representative of the logical operator $X_L\mathcal{S}$. Clearly, the two representatives have different weight.

A more dramatic example occurs in an odd distance $d$ planar surface code where people typically represent $X_L$ as a weight $d$ chain of physical $X$ operators along a straight line connecting two boundaries. However, an alternative representative is the operator that applies $X$ to *all* $d^2$ data qubits of the code.

### Weights in a tableau are not fixed under choice of generators

It is true that weights of the generators listed in a tableau remain unchanged under local Cliffords and qubit permutations. However, they do not remain fixed under multiplication of generators. Consequently, it is in fact *not true* that two different tableaus can only represent equivalent codes if all the weights of their Pauli strings are the same.

As a simple counterexample, consider the following two tableaus representing the group stabilizing $\mathrm{span}(|000\rangle,|001\rangle)$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
ZII\\
IZI
\end{array}\quad\quad\quad
\begin{array}{ccc}
ZZI\\
IZI
\end{array}
$$
The issue is that if $h,g_1,g_2,\dots,g_k$ are independent generators of a group $\mathcal{G}$ then so are $h,hg_1,hg_2,\dots,hg_k$ and the weights of $g_i$ and $hg_i$ are generally not the same.