# Does a $ [[5,1,2]] $ CSS code exist?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Every $ [[5,1,3]] $ code is equivalent to the perfect five qubit code with stabilizer generators
$$
XZZXI \\
IXZZX \\
XIXZZ  \\
ZXIXZ
$$
see for example

[Equivalence between Quantum Error Correcting codes and uniqueness of the $[\![5,1,3]\!]$ code](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30433/equivalence-between-quantum-error-correcting-codes-and-uniqueness-of-the-5?rq=1)

The $ [[5,1,3]] $ code is not equivalent to any CSS code. See

[CSS Code in disguise](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15432/css-code-in-disguise)

So no $ [[5,1,3]] $ CSS code exists.

My question is:

Does a $ [[5,1,2]] $ CSS code exist?

Comment: Just curious, why not take the $[[4,1,2]]$ and extend it by a single fixed qubit? You can always make codes 'worse' in this way.

Comment: @squiggles ya I thought about that and I realized I actually don't know how to just take a CSS code and extend it to a CSS code on one more quibt! What is the stabilizer for a $ [[5,1,2]] $ CSS code extended from a $ [[4,1,2]] $ CSS code?

Comment: e.g. for the $[[4,1,2]]$ given by $\langle ZZZZ, XXXX, ZZII\rangle$, you can make the $[[5,1,2]]$ code that is just appending a fixed '0' qubit $\langle ZZZZI, XXXXI, ZZIII, IIIIZ \rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S=\langle ZZZZZ, XXXXI, IXXXX, XXIXX\rangle $ with logicals $L_X = XXIII, L_Z= IZIZI$ should do the trick.

Comment: oh nice this even gives a $ [[5,2,2]] $ CSS code $S=\langle ZZZZZ, XXXXI, IXXXX \rangle $ and in general gives an $ [[2n+1,2n-2,2]] $ CSS code

Comment: You can also obtain a $[\![5,2,2]\!]$ CSS code by extending the $[\![4,2,2]\!]$ (CSS) code $S = \langle XXXX, ZZZZ \rangle$ by a single fixed qubit.

Answer (score 5):

A $[[5,1,2]]$ code occurs as a member of a family of hypergraph product codes with parameters $[[2d^2-2d+1,1,d]]$ codes : $[[5,1,2]],[[13,1,3]],[[25,1,4]],\cdots$. These are all CSS codes.
Here are (quantum) tanner graphs of the first three :[image]